# How to a pull out lines ONLY contains specific strings

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I would like a command that only output the lines start with "COLOUR=" and followed by ONLY either RED, GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, MAGENTA, CYAN, WHITE, or BLACK. Each color is separated by "|", order can be shuffled, the specified colours can be repeated, and case ignored ). Any help is greatly appreciated!

For example, i have a file which contains following lines...

```
COLOUR=ACK|RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|  
COLOUR=ACK|RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN     |WHITE|    TOMORROW  
COLOUR=RED|GREEN|yellow|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|white      
COLOUR=*BL*ACK|RE D|GREEN|YELLOWabc|  
COLOUR=BLACK|green|YELLOW|RED|WHiTE|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN  
COLOUR=BLACK|GR  
COLOUR=BLACK  
COLOUR=BLACK|
COLOUR=BLACK|BLACK|BLACK  
COLOUR=RED|RED|RED|BluE|YELLOW|yellow|CYAN|black  
COLOUR=COLOUR = COLOUR  
COLOUR=RED|HELLO|THANKS
```

and this is the output that I need:

```
COLOUR=RED|GREEN|yellow|BLUE|MAGENTA|white  
COLOUR=BLACK|green|YELLOW|RED|WHiTE|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN  
COLOUR=BLACK  
COLOUR=BLACK|BLACK|BLACK  
COLOUR=RED|RED|RED|BluE|YELLOW|yellow|CYAN|black
```

Comment: sorry I started the post the other day for a different topic, but didn't post, this is total different topic. I just changed the title

Comment: this is what i got after hours of research online...but it pulls out everything in file...

awk '/^COLOUR=/&&/BLACK|RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE/' IGNORECASE=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're after `COLOUR=` followed by a sequence of zero or more of `(RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK)` followed by a pipe, followed by a final one of the colours optionally followed by a pipe, all case-insensitive:

```
grep -Ei '^COLOUR=((RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK)\|)*(RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK)\|?$'
```

Given your input file, it produces the required output:

```
COLOUR=RED|GREEN|yellow|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|white
COLOUR=BLACK|green|YELLOW|RED|WHiTE|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN
COLOUR=BLACK
COLOUR=BLACK|BLACK|BLACK
COLOUR=RED|RED|RED|BluE|YELLOW|yellow|CYAN|black
```

Comment: thx for your input. The final one of colours should just end with one of those 8 colours, not a pipe.. I tried the code you provided just now, also taking out the /|..and..it greps nothing

Comment: There's a big difference betweeen `/|` as in your comment and `\|` as in my code.  It worked correctly for me on Mac OS X 10.9 with `bash` 3.2.51 and BSD `grep` (2.5.1-FreeBSD). One of your input lines had a `|` at the end (but an `ACK` near the beginning), so it wasn't clear whether that was wanted or not.  The `\|?` before the `$` in the regex allows for the trailing `|`; remove those three characters and the colour must end the line.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I did try your original line, with the example file above. it still greps nothing

Comment: Very curious.  I can't explain definitively why it won't work for you.  If you cut'n'paste the whole line and arrange for it to read your test data, and you ensure your test data has no trailing blanks, then it should work.  If your test data has trailing blanks, then you need to add something like blank-star before the `$`.  ISTR copy'n'pasting your data, observing a trailing blank, and reformatting it to remove all trailing white space.

Comment: I deleted some spaces as you said, and it works now. thank you so much! however, I cant give you a vote up cuz i dont have enough rep =s

Answer (score 0):

Try using following `perl` *one-liner*

```
perl -F'=|\|' -lane 'shift @F eq "COLOUR" and grep {!/RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK/i} @F or print' file
```

Output

```
COLOUR=RED|GREEN|yellow|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|white
COLOUR=BLACK|green|YELLOW|RED|WHiTE|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN
COLOUR=BLACK
COLOUR=BLACK|BLACK|BLACK
COLOUR=RED|RED|RED|BluE|YELLOW|yellow|CYAN|black
```

Comment: sorry I am a newbie. after i added this line, it just says command not found...do i need to specify in my bash script before using perl?
thanks

Comment: @BigDan: Type `which perl`. If it says command not found, you either don't have perl installed, or don't have it in your `$PATH`. If you don't have it installed, you'll have to try one of the other solutions offered.

Comment: @BigDan I believe `perl` is now very basic tool comes with most of linux/OS distributions. As described in previous comment by 'pgl', please check if you have `perl` installed. If not try `sudo apt-get install perl` if you're on Ubuntu

Comment: I just had a chance to try your code on my own PC. it works like charm!!
however, I cant really use perl at company fedora PCs, and those fedoras don't come with perl, and I don't have root privilege there..so I guess it has to be bash only. 
none of other solutions work for me so far, at least not on my end...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ c="RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK" }
    toupper($0) ~ "^COLOUR=(" c ")([|](" c "))*$"
' file
COLOUR=RED|GREEN|yellow|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|white
COLOUR=BLACK|green|YELLOW|RED|WHiTE|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN
COLOUR=BLACK
COLOUR=BLACK|BLACK|BLACK
COLOUR=RED|RED|RED|BluE|YELLOW|yellow|CYAN|black
```

Comment: Then you copy/pasted wrong or your input file isn't as you described or you're using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Maybe you have control characters or white space at the end of or in the middle of lines?

Comment: YES it works now, I left some space after the lines for some reason...anywayz, thanks so much! I am just trying to understand your code atm...so, at beginning you used "BEGIN{}" as a regex, then turn everything to uppercase by using toupper...i assume the $(0) means the whole line? and the "~" after means "grep ^COLOUR=(" c ")([|](" c "))*$'......am I correct? thanks again!

Comment: `c="RED|GREEN|YELLOW|BLUE|MAGENTA|CYAN|WHITE|BLACK"` defines a variable c which can be used later as part of a regex. Yes, `tolower($0)` converts the current input record (a line by default) to upper case. `~` is the regex comparison operator, like `==` is the equality comparison operator. And the rest is constructing a regex from strings and the `c` variable. The main difference between this and the grep solution is that with awk you can define and use a variable `c` rather than having to hard-code your list of colours more than once.